# Use conditional regex to generate filenames from url

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I get the following strings to output the following?

```
regex = '' # help me out here guys!

'baz/foobaryfobar/'.match(regex) #=> foobaryfobar

'baz/foobar'.match(regex) #=> foobar

'baz/foobar.jpg'.match(regex) #=> foobar

'baz/foobar.png'.match(regex) #=> foobar

'baz/foobar.gif'.match(regex) #=> foobar

'baz/foobar.jpeg'.match(regex) #=> foobar
```

Can it be done with one regex?

**update**

**Non-regex solutions to this more than welcome!**

Comment: what about `baz/foobar/andfoobar/and.jpg`??

Answer (score 3):

How about without Regex, but using [`extname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-extname), [`basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-basename) ?

```
def gen_file_name(string)
  File.basename(string,File.extname(string))
end

gen_file_name('baz/foobar.jpg') # => "foobar"
gen_file_name("baz/foobaryfobar/") # => "foobaryfobar"
gen_file_name('baz/foobar') # => "foobar"
```

Comment: He _specifically_ asked for a regular expression.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira Yes, because OP might not be aware of that there exist *non-regex* solution, which is much efficient as per OP's need.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Sorry, I did say I wanted regex but other solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the constraints, but maybe one of these

The dot is problematic in your description if it can be part of like `file.name.ext`
Otherwise,

Gets the filename in capture group 1 -

```
 # ([^/.]+)(?:\.[^/.]*|/)?\s*$

 ( [^/.]+ )       # (1)
 (?:
      \. [^/.]* 
   |  /  
 )?
 \s* 
 $
```

This uses lookahead, the match is the filename -

```
 # [^/.]+(?=(?:\.[^/.]*|/)?\s*$)

 [^/.]+ 
 (?=
      (?:
           \. [^/.]* 
        |  /  
      )?
      \s* 
      $ 
 )
```

Perl test case

```
my @ary = (
'baz/foobaryfobar/',
'baz/foobar',
'baz/foobar.jpg',
'baz/foobar.png',
'baz/foobar.gif',
'baz/foobar.jpeg'
);


for $url ( @ary )
{
      if ( $url =~ /[^\/.]+(?=(?:\.[^\/.]*|\/)?\s*$)/ ) {
           print "matched:  $&\n";
      }
}
```

Output >>

```
matched:  foobaryfobar
matched:  foobar
matched:  foobar
matched:  foobar
matched:  foobar
matched:  foobar
```